# Doctrine default value vs null insert

Tags: mysql, symfony, insert, doctrine, mariadb

There is something that bothers me. I've tried to find one clear answer but no luck so far.

I'm using Symfony3 and Doctrine2 and MariaDB.

Let's assume that I've created something like this in my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="status",
 *     type="boolean",
 *     options={"default": 0}
 * )
 */
private $status;
```

Now thanks to this I have field with default value of 0 in database:

```
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

But what's the point of having this when every time I try to save data into database(I'm trying to save only for example 1 out of 10 fields):

```
$story->setContent('Test Content');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($story);
$em->flush();
```

I get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'status' cannot  be null
```

Because, of course rest of the fields on the object are null.

I can work around this by setting the default values in the constructor or by allowing for null values in the DB.

What if I don't want to do this? Is there any other way that I am missing here?

So what I would like to know:

- are setting default value in entity or allowing nulls in DB only ways to do this?
- is there something wrong with my logic here?
- is there any cooler and cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Nope.  Not missing anything.  private $status = 0; is what you need.  Remember that entities are just plain old objects.  They don't get initialized based on the table definitions.

Comment: @Cerad - That's what I thought. It just seems so ugly. Doctrine requires a lot of house keeping around it to make it kinda smooth. Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: Keep in mind that not all databases support default and indeed, Doctrine itself has no direct support for it.  You can put anything you want in options and Doctrine will just concatenate it.  But yes, Doctrine can be a bit picky.  One reason why I seldom use the ORM anymore.

Comment: That's very true. I'm happy with this answer. I know it will be bit off topic but could you tell me in few words what kind of solution you like to use instead? I know it depends on project, size of it, purpose etc. I'm just asking in general what is your favorite thing to use.

Comment: It seems that all 3rd party software packages have some hiccup when it comes to mapping to 'good' SQL.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Anyway in most cases they are great help if you know how to use them - like in this case the devil is in the detail.

Comment: I use the Doctrine DBAL library to generate straight sql queries that give me exactly what I need and then either transform the results into objects or just keep the results as plain arrays depending on the need.  The ORM is great as long as your app fits it exactly.  Once you hit the limits then things can get awkward.

Comment: I think I will try to go with mixed approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like @Cerad commented, you just need to initialize the property in your actual entity class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     name="status",
 *     type="boolean",
 *     options={"default": 0}
 * )
 */
private $status = 0;
```

Comment: That's the approach I took. Just wanted to make sure that's the best way. Thanks for your input!

Comment: You could also initialize it in the constructor but it wouldn't really have any advantage

Comment: By this approach I meant constructor(I mentioned it in the question) :). For me in this case doing it in constructor keeps it a little bit cleaner. But I guess that's just my personal opinion.